# How to find a toast belonging

Tags: android, toast

when I using android phone (home screen).
a toast with some string popup somehow.
How can I find which apps did it?

I checked the log and can not find it.

I checked the apps which is running, but it is too much.

Answer (score 0):

directly you can't, but there is a way that may enables you to achieve that, at first there's no way to know which app that launched a toast, but you can know which package launched that Toast, you can listen to Toasts displayed and know it's contents by using [Accessibility Service Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html) class and listen to the `Notification_State_Changed`:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED; // to notify you when a notification happens
```

then using AccessibilityEvent to get the [event type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#getEventType%28%29)  and if it's a **Toast** you can get the [package name](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#getPackageName%28%29) of it's source which may enables you to figure out what's the app that fires it :

```
AccessibilityEvent.getEventType();
AccessibilityEvent.getPackageName():
```